# Golang Converting gopacket udpLayer to bytes and sending

Tags: sockets, go, layer, gopacket

I am using the gopacket/layers api to extract upd data out of a packet then sending it again via another udp stream, I am not sure if am doing this correct or not, also have been getting some errors, if anyone can point me in the correct direction that would be great
my code

```
conn, err := net.Dial("udp", 1.1.1.1)

udp, _ := updpLayer.(*layers.UDP)

/*now if i send it like this*/

conn.Write(udp)
/*i get the errors: cannot use udp (type *layers.UDP) as type []byte in argument to conn.Write*/

/*I tried to convert to bytes using unsafe*/

con := *(*[unsafe.Sizeof(udp)]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&udp))

/* I get cannot use conv (type [8]byte) as type []byte in argument to conn.Write */

/* I used ecoding/gob, but is it sending it as a byte stream?*/

encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
encoder.Encode(udp) //or Encode(udp)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Contents and Payload fields](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket/layers#BaseLayer) yet?

Comment: @Peter ya I do a look at it gave me exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updpLayer` doesn't represent the data directly, so trying to convert it to bytes is pointless. Read [the `Contents` or `Payload` field](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket/layers#BaseLayer) instead.